# What is the best way to get account actions in JSON format

Tags: cleos

I use:
$ cleos -u   get actions -j accountname

This returns all the actions in JSON format. However, it seems like the 'inline_traces' repeats a lot of the transactions (trx_ids are same) and require a recursive algorithm to read all the details. Is there a better or simpler approach?

Comment: you don't need to care about the inline traces if you only filter on your receiver.

Comment: Hmm... if I unset inline_traces key from my JSON data structure, I end up losing many transactions where target account is the receiver. For example, I had refund actions for premium names and they are only mentioned in the inline_trace part of the data. Weird!